# Over extrusion on Ender 3 with SKR mini E3 v1.2 and BMG clone (Bowden)

Tags: creality-ender-3, skr-mini-e3

I own two Ender3 printers, a stock one and one upgraded with SKR mini E3 v1.2 and BMG clone.

I calibrated the E-steps using the filament measurement method ~415 looks correct.

The machine severely over extrudes, reducing the flow rate to ~50 % looks right. I would say it pushes out about twice as much material then it should.

I am testing this using a simple one walled cube, sliced with Cura 4.7.1.

Printing this will have the wall thickens about double and several blobbing on the side the layers are restarted.

Printing the same G-code on the stock printer works without problems.

Printing from the card or using Repetier Server does not make any difference.

Comment: 415 is *not* correct, so much I can tell from my config. My Ener3 has: `#define DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT { 80, 80, 400, 93 }`

Comment: 93 is for the direct original extruder

Comment: the original *bowden* extruder. Direct is where the motor is on the carriage.

Comment: correct, i expressed wrongly, I meant "not geared" as the Bondtech BMG extruder it is, such extruder has a gear reduction, hence the bigger E-steps needed

Comment: Ok, you always should *calculate* the steps for the extruder. Can you give us numbers for the gear ratio?

Comment: 415 should be pretty close. My BMG clone runs at 407 (with 16x microstepping and 1.8° stepper motors).
93 is *obviously* for the stock extruder, which the asker replaced.

Make sure you have no flow rate modifiers active with `M221 S100`

Comment: At how many microsteps have you set the TMC2209? Default should be `#define E0_MICROSTEPS    16` as seen in the Configuration_adv.h.

Comment: I actually forgot about checking micro steps and really hoped this is, but turned out where 16. M221 returns `echo:E0 Flow: 100%` . I will now try to print the models from "Teaching Tech 3D Printer Calibration". Thank you a lot for all the good tips.